# inheritance design review

Tags: c#

i am build application that open Wireshark services (Wireshark has several services) in order to to different things on Wireshark files like Edit, change format, statistics etc...
each option usually use different service so i want to build my classes with inheritance
i was wonder if what i want to do is appropriate way or proper way:

main class WiresharkServices with the following members and method:
**this is the class that all the other classes should inherite from**

```
public class WiresharkProcesses
{
    protected string _filePath; //the file path who send to Wiresahrk process
    protected string _capinfos;
    protected string _dumpcap;
    protected string _editcap;
    protected string _mergecap;
    protected string _rawshark;
    protected string _text2pcap;
    protected string _tshark;
    protected string _wireshark;

    public void initializeServices()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark"))
        {
            _capinfos = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_capinfos.exe";
            _dumpcap = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_dumpcap.exe";
            _editcap = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\editcap.exe";
            _mergecap = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_mergecap.exe";
            _rawshark = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_rawshark.exe";
            _text2pcap = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_text2pcap.exe";
            _tshark = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_tshark.exe";
            _wireshark = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\_wireshark.exe";
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Wireshark"))
        {
            _capinfos = @"C:\Program File)\Wireshark\_capinfos.exe";
            _dumpcap = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_dumpcap.exe";
            _editcap = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\editcap.exe";
            _mergecap = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_mergecap.exe";
            _rawshark = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_rawshark.exe";
            _text2pcap = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_text2pcap.exe";
            _tshark = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_tshark.exe";
            _wireshark = @"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\_wireshark.exe";
        }
    }
}
```

when the application running i am check of course if Wireshark installed on the machine and if not throw exception and in Wireshark exist:

```
WiresharkServices wservices = new WiresharkServices();
wservices .initializeServices();
```

and in each class it's own methods.

child class example who receive file path to convert it to other Wireshark format:

```
public class Editcap : WiresharkProcesses
{
    private string _newFileName;

public void startProcess(string filePath)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    _newFileName = file.FullName.Replace(file.Extension, "_new") + ".pcap";
    ProcessStartInfo editcapProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format("\"{0}\"", _editcap))
    {
        Arguments = string.Format("{2}{0}{2} -F libpcap {2}{1}{2}", file.FullName, _newFileName, "\""),
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        ErrorDialog = false
    };

    using (Process editcap = Process.Start(editcapProcess))
    {
        editcap.WaitForExit();
    }
}

public string getNewFileName()
{
    return _newFileName;
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: as far as I can tell, none of your classes are extending other classes, so you don't seem to be using inheritance at all

Comment: this is the class that all the other classes should inherite from and my question is if this is proper way to build it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void initializeServices()
{
    string programFilesDirectory = "";

    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark"))
        programFilesDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\";

    else if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Wireshark"))
        programFilesDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\";

    _capinfos = programFilesDirectory + @"_capinfos.exe";
    _dumpcap = programFilesDirectory + @"_dumpcap.exe";
    _editcap = programFilesDirectory + @"editcap.exe";
    _mergecap = programFilesDirectory + @"_mergecap.exe";
    _rawshark = programFilesDirectory + @"_rawshark.exe";
    _text2pcap = programFilesDirectory + @"_text2pcap.exe";
    _tshark = programFilesDirectory + @"_tshark.exe";
    _wireshark = programFilesDirectory + @"_wireshark.exe";
```

Change it for start...